# Dictionary which has multiple dictionary corresponding to one key Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary, swift4.2

I have following format data (atleast 100,000 of these data blocks) in my database :

```
{
  "ax" : 1.232,
  "ay" : 1.897,
  "az" : -0.232
  "timestamp" : 151232326789
 }
```

which i am retrieving in my iOS Application in the format of a dictionary and parsing to a class model.
The above data is from sensor MPU6050, communicating to firebase usgin NodeMCU. Since NodeMCU doesnt have its own clock, to give the timestamp to data using `ServerValue.Timestamp` was the only option. Thus i couldn't properly structure my JSON Data that i now need to format on my iOS Application.

**I am extracting the `time` and `date` from the timestamp in my database**

This is the format i need in my frontend :

```
{
  Date1 : {
          Time1 :{ 
                "ax" : 1.232,
                "ay" : 1.897,
                "az" : -0.232
                  },
          Time2 :{ 
                "ax" : 1.232,
                "ay" : 1.897,
                "az" : -0.232
                  },
          Time3 :{ 
                "ax" : 1.232,
                "ay" : 1.897,
                "az" : -0.232
                  },
          Time4 :{ 
                "ax" : 1.232,
                "ay" : 1.897,
                "az" : -0.232
                  }
            }
  Date2 : {...similar as above.}
   }
```

I have tried using `NSMutableDictionary`, but data is getting messed up. Any Solution?

Comment: From where you get Date1, Date2... values ?

Answer (score 1):

I would structure this as one entity holding the sensor data for one date in an an array and storing instances of that entity in an array since dictionaries are unsorted.

```
var allData: [OneDayData]

struct OneDayData {
    var date: Date
    var sensorData: [SensorData]
}

struct SensorData {
    var time: String
    var ax: Double
    var ay: Double
    var az: Double
}
```

Note, I don't know how you convert the timestamp so I simply assumed it got converted into a Date and a String

Answer (score 1):

```
import Foundation

// define date - time interval for testing
let start = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2018, month: 1, day: 1))
let end = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2018, month: 1, day: 3))
let s = start!.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
let e = end!.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate

// generate array of random data with timestamp from defined date - time interval
var data: [[String: Double]] = []
(0..<10).forEach { _ in
    let ax = Double.random(in: -1.0...1.0)
    let ay = Double.random(in: -1.0...1.0)
    let az = Double.random(in: -1.0...1.0)
    // stamp between start and end date, with one second resolution
    let timestamp = TimeInterval.random(in: s...e).rounded()
    let record = ["ax": ax, "ay": ay, "az": az, "timestamp": timestamp]
    data.append(record)
}
```

What I got with `print(data as NSArray)`?

```
(
        {
        ax = "-0.9915295335923959";
        ay = "0.04220588780831558";
        az = "0.04947324263041164";
        timestamp = 536480749;
    },
        {
        ax = "0.8339518841345668";
        ay = "-0.8796254984325194";
        az = "0.9274526027609205";
        timestamp = 536596358;
    },
        {
        ax = "0.1892933660394962";
        ay = "0.2786212981444189";
        az = "-0.7010853895168836";
        timestamp = 536453459;
    },
        {
        ax = "-0.3879536539762585";
        ay = "-0.9881198368284949";
        az = "-0.8103733151058379";
        timestamp = 536574669;
    },
        {
        ax = "0.4386373099712233";
        ay = "-0.1082200532953461";
        az = "-0.5452489312143274";
        timestamp = 536515655;
    },
        {
        ax = "0.1021774847462089";
        ay = "-0.6414676993950421";
        az = "0.8826716373674426";
        timestamp = 536455164;
    },
        {
        ax = "0.1877861732407253";
        ay = "-0.6069605631703257";
        az = "-0.3766270018644693";
        timestamp = 536569833;
    },
        {
        ax = "0.3011539934614316";
        ay = "-0.8534914632655413";
        az = "0.652288374381045";
        timestamp = 536477646;
    },
        {
        ax = "-0.3087207248856481";
        ay = "0.566261641115348";
        az = "-0.6320769324182691";
        timestamp = 536563296;
    },
        {
        ax = "-0.5450288945879682";
        ay = "0.6143645223909975";
        az = "-0.8973854689667276";
        timestamp = 536609836;
    }
)
```

Now I have the data in the "same format" as you received (not JSON, but a Swift's Array of Dictionaries) and with a little help of next simple function

```
// extract date and time from timestamp value
func stamp(timestamp: TimeInterval)->(date: String, time: String) {
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: timestamp)
    return (DateFormatter.localizedString(from: date, dateStyle: .short, timeStyle: .none),
    DateFormatter.localizedString(from: date, dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .medium))
}
```

we are ready to group your data values by date and time, as required

```
// group data by date and time, if duplicated timestamp, use last value only
let result = data.reduce(into: [String:[String:[String: Double]]]()) { (result, record) in
    guard let ts = record["timestamp"] else { return }
    var record = record
    record["timestamp"] = nil
    let (date, time) = stamp(timestamp: ts)
    if result[date] == nil {
        result[date] = [time : record]
    } else {
        result[date]?[time] = record
    }
}
```

See how the result `[String:[String:[String: Double]]]` looks printed as NSDictionary

```
{
    "01/01/2018" =     {
        "00:50:59" =         {
            ax = "0.1892933660394962";
            ay = "0.2786212981444189";
            az = "-0.7010853895168836";
        };
        "01:19:24" =         {
            ax = "0.1021774847462089";
            ay = "-0.6414676993950421";
            az = "0.8826716373674426";
        };
        "07:34:06" =         {
            ax = "0.3011539934614316";
            ay = "-0.8534914632655413";
            az = "0.652288374381045";
        };
        "08:25:49" =         {
            ax = "-0.9915295335923959";
            ay = "0.04220588780831558";
            az = "0.04947324263041164";
        };
        "18:07:35" =         {
            ax = "0.4386373099712233";
            ay = "-0.1082200532953461";
            az = "-0.5452489312143274";
        };
    };
    "02/01/2018" =     {
        "07:21:36" =         {
            ax = "-0.3087207248856481";
            ay = "0.566261641115348";
            az = "-0.6320769324182691";
        };
        "09:10:33" =         {
            ax = "0.1877861732407253";
            ay = "-0.6069605631703257";
            az = "-0.3766270018644693";
        };
        "10:31:09" =         {
            ax = "-0.3879536539762585";
            ay = "-0.9881198368284949";
            az = "-0.8103733151058379";
        };
        "16:32:38" =         {
            ax = "0.8339518841345668";
            ay = "-0.8796254984325194";
            az = "0.9274526027609205";
        };
        "20:17:16" =         {
            ax = "-0.5450288945879682";
            ay = "0.6143645223909975";
            az = "-0.8973854689667276";
        };
    };
}
```

JSON part is up to you.

Comment: For now I went with global static struct. But I will give a shot to your solution as well. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary won't solve your problem. What you need here is array of custom models.

For example,

```
struct Time {
    var ax: Float
    var ay: Float
    var az: Float
}

struct Date {
    var times: [Time]
}

let array: [Date] = ... // parse your json into this
```

You need to write parsing logics of your json into this structure which can be done in various ways and, I believe, is out of the scope of initial question

Answer (score 0):

- jsonResponse is your array

  ```
          if let dictionary = jsonResponse as? [String : Any]
          {

                      let all=dictionary["Date1"] as? [[String : Any]]
                       if let all = all
                       {

                          let user:[String:Any]=all[0]["Time1"]! as! [String : Any]
                          let user2:[String:Any]=all[0]["Time2"]! as! [String : Any]

                          print(user["ax"] as? String)!,user["ay"] as? String)!,user["az"] as? String)!)                          
                          print(user2["ax"] as? String)!,user2["ay"] as? String)!,user2["az"] as? String)!)                            

                       }

          }
  ```